# Filtering long column names by one word and rename this columns

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, rename

My data frame is generated by the following code:

```
## Set seed for randomness in dummy data: ##
set.seed(123)

## Create data: ##
df.Data <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 110),
                 Germany = rnorm(110, 2, 1), "DE Nuclear 15min" = rnorm(110, 5, 2), "DE Photo" = rnorm(110, 5, 2),
                 "DE Wind Production" = rnorm(110, 4, 5), "DE Solar Product 15min" = rnorm(110, 2, 3), 
                 check.names = FALSE)

## Input vector: ##
v.data <- c("Wind", "Nuclear")
```

`v.data` is a variable vector, which is not always the same.

My question is, how can I filter my data frame so that only the following columns are saved in a new data frame: `Date` , `Germany` and the columns where the word/s that the vector contains? In this example, this would be column 3 and column 5.
And how can I rename the columns of the new data frame depending on which word is in the vector/column, e.g. `DE Nuclear 15min` should be renamed to `Nuclear` and so on...?

Comment: Yes, this is just an example data frame, Date and Germany don't have to be at the first and second column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this with the package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df.Data %>% select(Date, Germany, contains(v.data)) %>% rename_with(~v.data, contains(v.data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
out <- cbind(df.Data[c("Date","Germany")],df.Data[grep(paste0(v.data,collapse = "|"),names(df.Data))])
for (x in v.data) {
  out <- setNames(out,replace(names(out),grepl(x,names(out)),x))
}
```

such that

```
> head(out)
        Date  Germany  Nuclear       Wind
1 2020-01-01 1.439524 3.849306  9.0877932
2 2020-01-02 1.769823 6.215929 -1.9421702
3 2020-01-03 3.558708 1.764235  0.3919778
4 2020-01-04 2.070508 4.888876 11.5960886
5 2020-01-05 2.129288 6.038814  5.8869399
6 2020-01-06 3.715065 5.602307 -6.2611141
```